# Bluetooth sound via A2DP is stuttering on Linux Mint 20.1

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, bluetooth

I have a problem with my Bluetooth speakers (UE Megaboom 3) and headphones (Jabra Elite 65t): The sound is stuttering. I have a laptop with Windows10, MacOS and Linux Mint 20.1. The stuttering only happens on Mint, and only happens via BT. I'm using 5ghz wifi, so there should be no interference.

What I tried:

- Switching all devices off and on again.
- Deleting the bt-devices and pairing them again.
- Setting the latency to different values as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio
- Turning off timer-based scheduling in pulseaudio as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches,_skips_or_crackling

`lsusb | grep Bluetooth` gives me this:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
```

Any ideas what I could try next?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I don't know what caused the problem, but after much fiddling around, I fixed it by switching from blueberry to blueman as my bt-management software.

in the end, all it took was

`sudo apt-get remove blueberry`

and

`sudo apt-get install blueman`